# create mysql database with vba

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I use VBA mostly to access MySQL database and to downlaod data from the database into an excel worksheet. In order to open connection to MySQL server through vba i use the following code:

```
 Public Sub OpenConnection()
     Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
     conn.Open GetConnectionString()
 End Sub

 Function GetConnectionString() As String    
    Dim ConnectionString$
    ConnectionString$ = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 UNICODE Driver}; _                        
    SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=test;USER=root;PASSWORD=google;Option=3"
    GetConnectionString = ConnectionString$
 End Function
```

my question is that is there a VBA code i can use to create a new database in MySQL server and give it a specified name?

my MySQL server is version 5.6 if it helps.

Comment: how about just rifling off a query. You have a connection you say.  "create schema MySchema". "use MySchema". "create table x ( id int, x varchar(10))"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the comment Drew, I actually have other codes that enable me to enter query to MySQL database, the only this that was missing is the query to create a database if the database does not exits, anyways here is the whole code in order to create a MySQL database with VBA:

```
 Sub create_database()

   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Call OpenConnection

   Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
   Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

   Dim Query$

   Query$ = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Database_name"
   RS.Open Query$, conn

   Set RS = Nothing

   Call CloseConnection

 End Sub

 Public Sub OpenConnection()
     Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
     conn.Open GetConnectionString()
 End Sub

 Function GetConnectionString() As String    
    Dim ConnectionString$
    ConnectionString$ = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 UNICODE Driver}; _                        
    SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=test;USER=root;PASSWORD=google;Option=3"
    GetConnectionString = ConnectionString$
 End Function

 Public Sub CloseConnection()
   conn.Close
   Set conn = Nothing
 End Sub
```